# How add space between a word without delete the any letter

Tags: excel, vba

I tried below code to add space between "0a" but this code remove 0a and replaced space instead. I would like to get the output like  this - "0 a "  there is  any function to add space?

```
Sub ReSpace()
    Columns("H").Replace What:="0a", _
                           space:="0", _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           MatchCase:=False, _
                           SearchFormat:=False, _
                           ReplaceFormat:=False
    End Sub
```

Comment: What "space between a word" should mean? Looking to what you show, for a word of only two letters, should we imagine that "abcd" should be transformed in "a b c d "? If you do not need something general, why do not replace it with "0 a "?

Comment: The `Replacement` (not `space`) argument should just be `"0 a"`

Comment: Just a heads up, "0 a" will default to 12:00 AM

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Columns("H").Replace What:="0a", _
                       replacement:="0 a", _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       MatchCase:=False, _
                       SearchFormat:=False, _
                       ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You did not ask the clarification questions...

If you need to obtain a replacement string pattern of **any string** to be replaced, you can use the next function. The byte arrays offer a fast way to accomplish it:

```
Function strSpacesPattern(x As String) As String
  Dim arrB() As Byte: arrB = StrConv(x, vbFromUnicode) 'Place the string in a byte array (without the intermediary 0 if directly converting as arrB = x)
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  Dim arrB2() As Byte: ReDim arrB2(Len(x) * 2 - 1) 'declare and redim as second array able to keep the existing bytes, a space byte between each other and one at the end
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrB2)           'iterate between array (now empty) elements and fill it alternatively
     If i Mod 2 Then
        arrB2(i) = Asc(" ")           'a corresponding byte for space, in between each existing array byte
     Else
        arrB2(i) = arrB(k): k = k + 1 'each element of arrB
     End If
  Next i
  strSpacesPattern = StrConv(arrB2, vbUnicode) & " " 'reconvert the array in a string containing each string byte separated by spaces plus an ending space.
End Function
```

It can be tested/used in the next way:

```
Sub testStringSpacesPattern()
   Dim x As String: x = "abcd"
   Debug.Print """" & strSpacesPattern(x) & """"
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The next function uses the byte array containing a zero after each byte (without using StrConv):

```
Function strSpacesPatt(x As String) As String
  Dim arrB() As Byte: arrB = x   'Place the string in a byte array
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  Dim arrB2() As Byte: ReDim arrB2(Len(x) * 4 - 1) 'declare and redim as second array able to keep the existing bytes, a space byte between each other and a space at the end
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrB2) Step 4        'iterate between array (now empty) elements and fill it
        arrB2(i) = arrB(k): k = k + 1      'add the real byte
        arrB2(i + 1) = 0: k = k + 1        'add the intermediary zero
        arrB2(i + 2) = Asc(" "): arrB2(i + 3) = 0 'add the space byte and the intermediary 0
  Next i
  x = arrB2: strSpacesPatt = x & " ": Exit Function
End Function
```

Tested as:

```
Sub testStringSpacesPattern()
   Dim x As String: x = "abcde"
   Debug.Print """" & strSpacesPatt(x) & """"
End Sub
```

In fact, I've just played with VBA, taking the supposition as a challenge... :)

Comment: Nice idea +:); some clarifying words to byte arrays and `StrConv()` would be helpful for not so experienced users. @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M I am not sure I accurately understood what OP needs, he did not answer the clarification questions... I've just took advantage of it to take a challenge to create a replace string pattern, consisting in each initial string digit separated by a space, plus an ending space. I will try clarifying what each code line does...